# How to solve git describe --match limitation

Tags: git, glob

I'm using `git describe --long --tags` to automatically generate version strings from repo tags. So that if I have **1.20** tag I get **1.20-5-g27ba6e8** version string in my code.

Now I'm only interested in tags which in regexish look like `^\d+\.\d+$` (I don't want `describe` to see any other descriptive tags).

`git describe` has --match switch which would have been exactly what I need if not for the fact that the match is done using glob patterns.

How can I limit a glob pattern only to two numbers (which can have any number of digits!) delimited with a dot?

Answer (score 4):

> How can I limit a glob pattern only to two numbers (which can have any number of digits!) delimited with a dot?

You can't. The biggest problem is that glob patterns can't repreat last pattern one or more times, there is no `+` operator like in regex. The closest you can do is:

```
[0-9]*.[0-9]*
```

Sadly the `*` matches *any* characters. `bash` shell solves that issue by introducing extended glob, in the form of `+([0-9]).+([0-9])`. **But** you can specify `--match` multiple times and generate patterns for all possible combinations (puff):

```
# generated with:
# p="[0-9] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9]"; for i in $p; do for j in $p; do echo "--match \"$i.$j\""; done; done | paste -sd' '
# should handle up numbers up to 3 digits
git describe --long --tags --match "[0-9].[0-9]" --match "[0-9].[0-9][0-9]" --match "[0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]" --match "[0-9][0-9].[0-9]" --match "[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]" --match "[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]" --match "[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9]" --match "[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]" --match "[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

I also recommend to contribute to open source and implement something along `--regexmatch` to [`git describe`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/describe.c#L186). The other way round is to do the filtering by yourself and pass the tag back to `git-describe` to describe it. In POSIX shell that could be something along:

```
git tag --sort=committerdate | grep '^[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+$' | tail -n1 | xargs git describe --long --tags --exact-match --match
```